# WS-X45-SUP6-E / WS-X45-SUP7-E compatibility w/4510R (non-E)

Tags: cisco, switch

The EOL announcement for the Cisco WS-X4516 on a 4510R (non-E series chassis) states that the WS-X45-SUP6-E is a replacement though this SUP is for the E-series chassis.  Incidentially, the SUP6 is also EOL and replaced with the WS-X45-SUP7-E.

**Can these E-series SUPs be used to replace 4516 non-E series SUPs?  My VAR says "no" after checking with Cisco. Is the VAR or these EOL announcements correct (or am I misreading them)?**

**With the 4500 non-E series EOL, I'm looking for any upgrade options on the SUPs short of having to replace the entire chassis and modules if possible.**

[End-of-Sale and End-of-Life Announcement for the Select Cisco Catalyst 4500 Non-E-Series Supervisor Engines](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps4324/eol_c51_574542.html)

[End-of-Sale and End-of-Life Announcement for the Cisco Catalyst 4500 Supervisor Engine 6-E](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps4324/eol__C51-726869.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sup6E is supported in non-E chassis and it supports legacy modules.

> The Cisco Catalyst 4500 Supervisor Engine 6-E is compatible with classic Cisco Catalyst 4500 line cards, chassis, and power supplies, providing full investment protection. (Source: [Sup6E Data sheet](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/modules/ps2797/ps9294/product_data_sheet0900aecd806df543_ps4324_Products_Data_Sheet.html))

Sup7E requires an E chassis

> Cisco Catalyst Supervisor Engine 7-E is supported in Cisco Catalyst 4500 E-Series chassis only. (Source: [Sup7E Data sheet](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps4324/data_sheet_c78-612364_ps2797_Products_Data_Sheet.html))